# Select data from sqlite iOS has null statement sometime

Tags: ios, sqlite

I am selecting data from sqlite database. Problem is that using following code it works some time. But lets say we call this method for any other table twice then it shows null select statement for other method. Is any thing wrong in method so that if we use same for other tables some time it works some time not.

```
-(void)getAssessmentNumber:(NSString *)dbPath{
    appDelegate=[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    NSString*fileDBPath=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Database" ofType:@"sqlite"];
    if (sqlite3_open([fileDBPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        //  NSLog(@"%@",[self getDBPath]);
        NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Select Am.AssessmentID , Am.AssessmentName From AssessmentMaster Am LEFT JOIN AssessmentDepartmentMapping M ON M.AssessmentID = Am.AssessmentID LEFT JOIN DepartmentListing d ON d.departmentID =M.departmentID where d.departmentID = '%@'",appDelegate.departmentID];
        NSLog(@"%@",querySQL);
        const char *sql = [querySQL UTF8String];
        sqlite3_stmt *selectstmt;
        NSError *error;
        [appDelegate.assessmentNumberArray removeAllObjects];

        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &selectstmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            while (sqlite3_step(selectstmt) == SQLITE_ROW)
            {
                NSInteger primaryKey = sqlite3_column_int(selectstmt, 0);
                AssessmentListening   *asmObj = [[AssessmentListening alloc] initWithPrimaryKey:primaryKey];
                asmObj.assessmentID=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",primaryKey];

                asmObj.assessmentName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 1)];

                [appDelegate.assessmentNumberArray addObject:asmObj];
            }
        }
        else {
            NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
        }

        //  sqlite3_finalize(selectstmt);
    }
    sqlite3_close(database);
}
```

Is this fine for getting the data from table?

Comment: are u saying that querySQL is getting nil ?

Comment: @TejaNandamuri sqlite3_stmt selectstmt is getting null thats why it does not sqlite_step3

Comment: Why are you calling `sqlite3_prepare_v2` twice? Just call it once. And why do you log an error that states you couldn't create the database when you are unable to prepare the statement?

Comment: @rmaddy should call != or ==  statements

Comment: @DilshadAli I have no idea how your last comment applies to my previous comment.

Comment: @rmaddy I have edited code please see

Comment: Get rid of the user of the `NSError *error`. It's not used anywhere. If there is a problem, use `sqlite3_errmsg(database)` to see the error.

Comment: And put back the call to `sqlite3_finalize`.

Comment: @rmaddy should I put sqlit3_finalize where it is now

Comment: It should really go at the end of the `if` block for `sqlite3_prepare_v2`. It will work where it is but there's no reason to finalize a statement that didn't successfully prepare.

Comment: @rmaddy can you please edit in code

Answer (score 1):

Your code needs a little cleanup.

```
- (void)getAssessmentNumber:(NSString *)dbPath {
    NSString *fileDBPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Database" ofType:@"sqlite"];
    if (sqlite3_open([fileDBPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
        appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        [appDelegate.assessmentNumberArray removeAllObjects];

        const char *sql = "Select Am.AssessmentID, Am.AssessmentName From AssessmentMaster Am LEFT JOIN AssessmentDepartmentMapping M ON M.AssessmentID = Am.AssessmentID LEFT JOIN DepartmentListing d ON d.departmentID = M.departmentID where d.departmentID = ?";
        sqlite3_stmt *selectstmt;

        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &selectstmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
            sqlite3_bind_text(selectstmt, 0, [appDelegate.departmentID UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

            while (sqlite3_step(selectstmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                NSInteger primaryKey = sqlite3_column_int(selectstmt, 0);
                AssessmentListening *asmObj = [[AssessmentListening alloc] initWithPrimaryKey:primaryKey];
                asmObj.assessmentID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", primaryKey];

                asmObj.assessmentName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 1)];

                [appDelegate.assessmentNumberArray addObject:asmObj];
            }

            sqlite3_finalize(selectstmt);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Unable to prepare statement: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        }

        sqlite3_close(database);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Unable to open the database from %@: %s", fileDBPath, sqlite3_errmsg(database);
    }
}
```

Note all of the changes:

1. Only close the database if it is opened.
2. Only finalize the statement if it is prepared.
3. Don't build queries with `stringWithFormat`. Use the proper `sqlite3_bind_xxx` function to bind the values to the query. This ensures special characters are escaped and properly deals with quoting.
4. Use proper error checking. Use `sqlite3_errmsg` to get the error.

Comment: data base path should I give like this if I am using in entire app. Or should copy the database in documents directory

Comment: It's read-only in the app bundle. If you ever need to write to the database then you will need to first copy it to the Documents folder and then you should always open the database in the Documents folder.

Comment: so lets say I need to write also so in AppDelegate I copy to Documents foldeer and then use that path over here for Select querry also

Comment: Yes. Once you make the copy you never use the original ever again for any reason (unless you wish to reset your database back to the original again).

Comment: And what's the error? This is the whole reason for `sqlite3_errmsg` - so you know why it failed.

Comment: Unable to prepare statement: database is locked

Comment: You must have other database code that isn't cleaning itself up properly. Make all of your database similar to the code in my answer. Make sure you always close the database, always finalize statements, etc. Also make sure you aren't doing database stuff on two separate threads at the same time.

Comment: I am calling this at the end of first view controller     [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(finalizeKeyMatrics) toTarget:self withObject:nil];

Comment: after this I am calling above method